# Calling CSS animation on click with Angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, forms, animation

I have got a form and I would like to implement the following behaviour :

I you submit my form by clicking on the submit button and the form is invalid, the button shakes from right to left for 1.5 second.
You won't be able to send the form until it is not valid.

Currently when the user clicks on the submit button, the function submit() is checking all the fields and if the form is valid, a variable formValid becomes true, otherwise it becomes false.

What I did concerning my button is adding it a ng-class which applies, if the formValid is false, a CSS class for the animation.

To detect the end of the animation, I tried a few things including jQuery function :

```
var anim = document.getElementById("animatedButton");
anim.addEventListener('animationend', $scope.AnimationListener());
anim.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', $scope.AnimationListener())
```

But with the digest cycle ect, it didn't work and I should not use JQuery to solve this issue.

I know I could use ngAnimate but I am looking for another solution.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not use plain javascript then?

Comment: I need an Angular way only..

Comment: Check these 2 links; 1: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animateCss  2: https://css-tricks.com/animations-the-angular-way/